# What is the meaning of "sought to" in Exodus 4:24?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 4:24
English Standard Version

> At a lodging place on the way the LORD met him and **sought to** put him to death.

What is the meaning of "sought to"? If God intended to kill him, he could have done so easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of meaning associated with the word בָּקַשׁ (baqash) can be gauged by the variety of translations both in Ex 4:25 and elsewhere.  BDB lists at least 6 basic meanings and several sub-meanings. These include:

seek, desire, try, attempt, require, asked, look for, intend to, etc, etc.  The various translation of Ex 4:24 are even more enlightening:

- NIV, NLT, BSB, CEV, ISV: about to
- ESV, KJV, NKJV, NASB, HCSB, ASV: sought to
- CSB - intended to
- GNT: tried to

Of these, I prefer the first option above, thus rendering Ex 4:24 as:

> At a lodging place on the way, the LORD met Moses and was about to
> kill him.

Note the comments of the Cambridge commentary:

> 24. **sought to kill him** ‘A primitive anthropomorphic way of saying that Moses fell dangerously ill’ (McNeile). The reason is commonly
>     supposed to have been his neglect to circumcise his child (Genesis 17)
>     But, as Di. remarks, ‘there is nothing in the narrative to suggest
>     this; and an acquaintance with the command of Genesis 17 is as little
>     pre-supposed by it as by Joshua 5:9’ (see further below, p. 33).

Benson is more helpful:

> **and sought to kill him** — He appeared in a threatening posture, probably with a sword drawn in his hand, or inflicted upon him some
> disease which threatened him with death. This was a great change: very
> lately God was conversing with him as a friend, and is now coming
> forth against him as an enemy. The cause seems to have been Moses’s
> neglecting to circumcise his son; which, perhaps, was the effect of
> his being unequally yoked with a Midianite, who was too indulgent of
> her child, and Moses so of her.

I can easily imagine that there had been some significant quarrels between Moses and Zipporah about their son's circumcision and so God had to threaten the life of Moses in order to convince Zipporah to allow the porocedure.  It worked!

Answer (score 1):

There is far more to this passage than can be ‘answered’ by analysing the word ‘sought’ (bāqaš) -

An overview. The word ‘bāqaš’ would arguably be better translated as ‘required’. This legitimate translation fits the overall intent.

First, the pronoun ‘him’, as in the Lord sought to kill ‘him’ does *not* refer to Moses. It refers to his son.

The requirement, or rather the ‘sign’ to be ‘under’ the Abrahamic covenant was circumcision. In Egypt the Israelites were ‘protected’ by their God, protected from the ‘gods’ of Egypt. Here we have Moses and family travelling to Egypt.

However Moses’s family was not ‘’protected’ under this covenant at the time of this encounter, so Satan, because Moses’s son was not [yet] a covenant ‘child’, therefore had a ‘claim’ (i.e. ownership) over him.

This was rectified in the following verse.

**EXODUS 4:25** *Then Zipporah took a sharp stone and cut off the foreskin of her son and cast it at Moses’ feet, and said, “Surely you are a husband of blood to me!”*

So the meaning of ‘sought’ is best moved to using ‘required’, and I have provided a reason and meaning for the use of ‘bāqaš’.

Comment: @Dottard Yes, I completely messed that. I’ve (embarrassingly) made the needed edits. The point is (and was, although originally presented in-errantly) that the intended ‘victim’ was/is *not* Moses

Answer (score 1):

Most translations have "sought to kill", which is as good a translation as any. The issue here is not grammar, since the passage is straightforward and poses no translational difficulties. Rather the issue is interpretive in nature.

The best interpretation of this passage that I've seen is by John I Durham, in the Word Biblical Commentary[1]. For completeness, I've included the bulk of Durham's argument, but will summarize it here:

1. The theories that Moses was not the object to be killed but his son are "fanciful" and have no basis in the text. Moses is the center of the story.
2. The issue is that Moses was not circumcised -- this despite medieval rabbinical traditions that say Moses was born circumcised(!). This has been a long running problem for rabbinical commentary, as Moses was raised in Egypt and nowhere in the scripture is his circumcision mentioned -- this passage is as close as it gets.
3. But Moses could not be circumcised that night as he needed to travel quickly back to Egypt. What follows then is a strange circumcision, where Zipporah circumcises his son (who will not be travelling to Egypt) and touches Moses' genitals (euphemistically, the 'feet') with the the bloody foreskin of the son, proclaiming "You are a bridegroom of blood"
4. The author explains that "You are a bridegroom of blood" is an ancient wedding vow, dating back to the time when adults were circumcised as a pre-marital ceremony, and thus it would need an explanation to the reader of Genesis, which is provided by the redactor in v26b. The point being, and this is emphasized by the author of Genesis as well, that Moses is deemed circumcised as a result of this ritual.

My own addition would be that this idea of vicarious fulfillment of the law prefigures how Christ satisfies the law for us as well. The fact that Israel was given the law by a murderer who escaped justice, married gentiles, and wasn't even circumcised, poses no end of problems for those of a more pharisaical bent, and creates all sorts of very creative textual readings, such as Moses being born circumcised, or acting only in self-defense, or that his wives converted before he married them, etc.

But for those who see in the text a justification by faith and the blood of an innocent, Moses is the perfect vessel to ascend the mountain, see God by the power of grace, and bring his revelation back to Israel.

Here is an excerpt of Durham's argument:

> it is hardly reasonable to claim that anyone except Moses is the
> object of Yahweh’s encountering action. Moses is the center of
> Yahweh’s concern everywhere else in the section, even in the intrusive
> verses involving Aaron. **The sudden emergence to the forefront of
> Moses’ son would make no sense whatever in such a sequence. The reason
> for this attack, as the redactor’s explanatory note in v 26b makes
> clear, is that Moses had not previously been circumcised. The
> difficulty of such a conclusion for the later generations of Jewish
> scholars, who proved themselves capable of contending that Moses,
> along with other great OT heroes, was born circumcised (Vermes, NTS 4
> [1958] 314–15), has made it difficult also for a great many Christian
> scholars. But no other explanation of this passage in this context
> answers more questions than it raises.** Sasson (JBL 85 [1966] 473–74)
> has pointed out convincingly that Egyptian circumcision was not only
> performed on adults, but was, by comparison with Hebrew circumcision,
> merely a partial circumcision. Indeed, he contends (475–76) that
> circumcision may well have come to Egypt from North Syria, where it
> was practiced early in the third millenium B.C. For whatever reasons,
> the compiler who set vv 24–26 in their present context had apparently
> reached a conclusion confirmed by these facts. Perhaps he combined the
> abnormal circumstances by which the infant Moses had to be hidden away
> at birth with some knowledge of the Egyptian practice and even a
> belief that the circumcision of infant boys was a late development in
> Israel’s life. Quite possibly, he too was searching for some reason
> for Yahweh’s serious encounter. Whatever the case, he clearly believed
> that Moses was uncircumcised and that Yahweh determined to stop him en
> route to Egypt for that reason. Zipporah, the only person available to
> perform the rite, seizes the mandatory flint cutting tool (Josh 5:2–9;
> cf. Sasson, JBL 85 [1966] 474) and circumcises not Moses, who would
> have been temporarily incapacitated by the surgery (cf. Gen 34:18–31)
> at a crucial time when he could no longer delay his journey, but her
> son. For the child, who was not to make the journey to Egypt in any
> case, the effects of the circumcision would be less problematic. To
> transfer the effect of the rite, Zipporah touched the severed foreskin
> of her son to the genitals of Moses, intoning as she did so the
> ancient formula recalling circumcision as a premarital rite: “For a
> bridegroom of blood you are to me!” This ancient phrase, as Mitchell
> [VT 19 [1969] 94–105, 111–12) has demonstrated, is a phrase of marital
> relationship—and it was already old enough at the time of the
> compilation of this sequence to require a specific comment by the
> redactor that the context of reference for the phrase was circumcision
> (v 26b). The final establishment of circumcision as the crucial point
> of these verses is of course that Zipporah’s action worked and that
> Yahweh thus “fell back” or “backed off” from Moses. The point at issue
> in vv 24–26 is thus that Moses had not been circumcised or, at best,
> had received only the partial circumcision of the Egyptians, referred
> to in Josh 5:9 as a “disgrace” or “reproach” (חרפה). A comparable
> memory for the compiler of this section may indeed have been the one
> recorded now in Josh 5:2–9, which reports the circumcision of all
> those born in the wilderness following the exodus who had not been
> circumcised and so had to be before the crossing of the Jordan for the
> conquest and settlement of the promised land. At the beginning of
> Moses’ special mission for Yahweh, this omission, or perhaps this
> “Egyptian disgrace,” had to be remedied. Vv 24–26 pose the problem and
> describe its immediate and surely temporary remedy. The language of v
> 24, “sought to put him to death,” may reflect an earlier layer of the
> story, but here it describes the seriousness of the crisis and
> indicates dramatically that Yahweh is still very much in charge. The
> language may be compared to the language of the account of the testing
> of Abraham’s faith (Gen 22:2) or of the struggle of Jacob at Jabbok
> (Gen 32:22–32). Zipporah’s reaction to the crisis is a vicarious
> circumcision of Moses to prevent his being painfully crippled at the
> beginning of the most important undertaking of his life. And what
> Zipporah says is the ritual statement which accompanied the premarital
> circumcision as a declaration to a young man’s in-laws that he was of
> an age appropriate for marriage. The “bridegroom of blood” of
> circumcision was being prepared to become a bridegroom of a bride.
> Perhaps there was a similar ritual statement in the wedding ceremony.
> To the redactor who included this narrative in Exod 4, this ritual
> phrase was already arcane enough to require the explanation he
> appended at v 26b.

---

[1] Durham, J. I. (1987). Exodus (Vol. 3, pp. 58–59). Dallas: Word, Incorporated.